# "in replacement of" vs "in place of"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, idioms

What is the difference between "in replacement of" and "in place of"?

I was using "in replacement of" in this sentence:

> Shah and his team managed to devise a system that allows their robots
> to map a single 2D topological graph of the environment **in
> replacement of** the traditional 3D model that is widely used in
> previous years.

My prof edited this to "in place of" and I am not sure why. I tried to google it but nothing seems to come up.

Comment: To put it very briefly: *in replacement of* just isn't what we say, idiomatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher was right to correct you. Maybe next time trust his/her judgement? And there is a reason nothing came up on Google: "<strike>in replacement of</strike>" is not correct English, it is a non-existent expression.

The correct English expressions are:

**instead of**
**in place of**

"As a replacement for" is a possible combination but there's a difference in meaning. See @PeterJennings's comment.

In your text:

*... that allows their robots to map a single 2D topological graph of the environment **instead of** / **in place of** the traditional 3D model ...*

Answer (score 0):

Think of "in place of" as "instead of", e.g.

> I used jam in place of marmalade -> I used jam instead of marmalade

For "in replacement of", we do not use this as it does not sound right in any context, e.g.

> I bought a new fridge in replacement of the broken one

Saying "I bought a new fridge in place of the broken one" **can** work, but does not make sense when translating to "instead of" -> "I bought a new fridge instead of the broken one", so it's better to use "to replace" or "as a replacement for" here.

> I bought a new fridge [to replace/as a replacement for] the broken one

Comment: As a native BrE speaker, "in replacement of" doesn't sound right to me in any context. I would have said "as a replacement for" instead. So "I bought a new fridge as a replacement for the broken one" or even better just "I bought a new fridge to replace the broken one"

Comment: @PeterJennings It is grammatically correct though, but thanks for your opinion I will edit my answer

Comment: @DailFrost That's fine. I never intended to imply that "in replacement of" was ungrammatical, just that, as we agree, it doesn't sound right and I can't remember having heard or seen that phrase used in practice.